# Why is the share button icon misaligned in my Spotify app?

Tags: html, css, button, spotify

I have a share button in the Spotify app I'm developing. I'm using the exact html supplied in the [developer guidelines 'buttons' section](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/guidelines/#buttons), and I have also imported the standard CSS files.

My button renders with the icon missaligned (too low), e.g.

[image: missaligned share icon]

I notice this also occurs in other Spotify apps, e.g. Pitchfork

[image: missaligned share icon]

In native Spotify pages the icon is positioned correctly, e.g.

[image: share icon with correct alignment]

Is this a bug in the standard Spotify's app CSS, or is it a problem with my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely a problem with Spotify's CSS. The positioning of the icon is defined at shared.css line 135:

[image: shares.css source of the problem]

I added the following to my stylesheet to put it back to the right place:

```
.button.icon .share::before {
    top: -15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try with `vertical-align: top` or `middle` for this element

Comment: Thanks, I'm really more interested whether this is a Spotify bug, or a problem in my app. I've removed the secondary question about how to fix the alignment so that this is clearer  (I can probably figure out how to hack the CSS if needed).

Answer (score 1):

We are working on a fix for this in the next version of our API. Thanks for reporting!